# QtCreator for windows: is it possible to build 64 bit .exe?

Tags: qt-creator

Is it any way in QtCreator for windows to build a 64-bit executable? (I need to use a COM object as INPROC and this object is only available for 64 bit architecture)

Comment: Just googling (as you did already as I can see) - if I read this correctly: http://lists.trolltech.com/pipermail/qt-creator/2009-May/003185.html it seems to be possible to build 64 bit apps with it?

Comment: It's only available now. The link was dead last time i has checked. Also, it requires to recompile a QT libraries for 64-bit and i'm not sure how to do it correctly ^_^.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not see any reason why not.  You would need:

1. To be working on a 64-bit processor,
2. Ensure you have the Visual Studio 64 bit edition
3. Compile Qt on that 64 Bit setup
4. Compile QtCreator on that setup

The email says that debugging tools would also need to be compiled.  I am not sure which debugger QtCreator uses but I would image it would be open source and you could compile it on that setup anyway.

Qt probably do not do it by default because they already produce loads of different builds for all the platforms they support and there has not yet been a large demand for 64bit windows desktop applications.

Comment: Incase anyone appears from Google and is struggling with this, rather than going through the pain of compiling QT for x64, there is a project that produces the builds; http://code.google.com/p/qt-msvc-installer/

Answer (score 1):

*Pekka Gaiser* correctly pointed to an email from Trolltech. Basically, that's it :)

Specifically: Seemingly there is no 64 bit cross-compiler for Windows (due to that, there is no 64bit VLC for Windows). Therefore, the Microsoft compiler must be used. Unfortunately, Creator's support for Microsoft's toolchain is limited (although they make big steps towards supporting it fully).

Again: The email pointed to by *Pekka Gaiser* contains the information and links for using Qt Creator with Microsoft's 64bit toolchain.